# Find out when a file is being accessed from another application

Tags: delphi

If I have a file that is opened in the memory of my application, is there any way I could find out when another application tries to overwrite it? The other app will get a sharing violation and I need to log that. If it helps in any way, I know which application tries to overwrite the file.

Comment: Yes, I hope it might be enough for you to wait for the `FindFirstChangeNotification` (or eventually by `ReadDirectoryChangesW`).

Comment: @Victoria I don't think either of those calls will help, since they occur when the file is actually changed, rather than when a process *attempts* to change it

Comment: @Dave, you're right. Taking back my comment..

Comment: Without writing a lower level kernel driver to monitor filesystem activity, the only option I can think of is to inject a DLL into the other app and have the DLL hook `CreateFile()` directly, and then the hook can communicate back to your main app.